# is there a way to manipulate image without saving to a file first?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-requests

I'm trying to collect img data for my ML/DL project.

I need facial data so, I have to detect the face and crop around it.

I have a bunch of img URLs that I searched online.

Normally I would save them in a file using requests library, but would it be possible to do it in-memory?

```py
response = requests.get(IMG_URL)
img_byte = response.content
# Do image processing without saving to a file
```

I looked at some image libraries in python such as PIL or OpenCV,

but they all seems to get images loaded from a file in first place.

I think I could speed up the process if I don't save temporary files. (I/O is a big bottleneck)

I tried playing around with BytesIO functions but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*`BytesIO`* is the way to go!. You can store the binary data returned by the request to the [In-memory byte buffer(`BytesIO`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) and pass it to [*`Image.open`*](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open)

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> img_obj = Image.open(BytesIO(r.content))
```

The only requirement of the [`Image.open` API](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) is that the `fp` argument must be *a filename (string), `pathlib.Path` object or **a file object. The file object must implement `file.read`, `file.seek`, and `file.tell` methods**, and be opened in binary mode*.

[`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) implements all these methods.

```
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>>
>>> buffer = BytesIO()
>>> hasattr(buffer, 'read') and hasattr(buffer, 'tell') and hasattr(buffer, 'seek')
True
```